# Candidates being in the same timezone a problem?

Tags: discussion, election

I had a look at the moderator candidates and 3 very good candidates reside more or less in the same timezone (according to their profile-page).

So I was wondering if that's something to consider for the moderator election? If we had moderators from around the globe, site moderation could be more or less 24/7?

What's your take on this? In the current state of gamedev SE it's probably not a very big issue, but might be in the future when the site continues to grow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As (if?) the site grows, we'll hopefully get some community moderators, so it won't be as big an issue. For now, the site is pretty dead during non-US times anyway.